# Number of coins needed to make change

Tags: code-golf, sequence, arithmetic, integer-partitions

Relatable scenario: I'm going to the store to buy a single item, but only have a $100k bill. As a result, I need exactly $99,979 in change, and in the fewest coins/bills possible because I'm quite obviously a very practical person.

The denominations of these coins/bills follow the [hyperinflation sequence](https://oeis.org/A051109): \$1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200\$, and so on.

(I'd proposed an OEIS sequence for this, but the first 100k terms are identical to another one so it got rejected)

**Task:**

Given an amount of money as a nonnegative integer, such as \$73\$, return the minimum number of coins/bills needed to total to that amount. In this example, it would be \$4\$. The coins required would be \$50 + 20 + 2 + 1\$.

As per the standard rules for [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence), you can also choose to return all terms up to an inputted index, or return a (potentially infinite) lazy list or generator that represents the whole sequence.

**Test cases:**

```
0       0
1       1
2       1
3       2
4       2
5       1
6       2
7       2
8       3
9       3
10      1
11      2
20      1
30      2
37      4
90      3
111     3
147     5
1000    1
1002    2
1010    2
12478   9
```

**Other:**

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes per language wins!

Comment: @RobinRyder Yes, sorry about that

Comment: Very closely related, if not practically a duplicate: [Minimally Making Change](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/220864/minimally-making-change)

Comment: @Etheryte The premise is similar, but the challenge is very different. I doubt the solutions to the two will be anywhere near similar.

Comment: Can I take input as a list of digits?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing No, sorry.

Comment: Closely related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/210671/find-the-largest-banknote/210701

Comment: The store manager is going to get suspicious...

Answer (score 14):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>36</s>  35 bytes

Similar to other answers. Using a Black Magic formula instead of a lookup table.

```javascript
f=n=>n&&(n%10)**29%3571%4+f(n/10|0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdBBDoIwEAXQvadgAy0YZaYtFhZ4F4JiNKQ1Ylx590ow0aak0@3Ln/6ZW/fqpv5xvT93xp7Ozg2taY8my7hJEfKiEE0qK42p2g7clAhvyF1vzWTH8360Fz5wBiyZX54nZZnAJkD0EEMUFEoPRYiKwooae6CSmsLaQxliQyEuJ4oUQmTxPwWVlEAkpf6jWrX1kuu2S6MYKv3Dar0nzINjewIIFmuLgBBHoXTNvti4Dw)

[Here](https://tio.run/##Rc9ta4MwEAfw936K/4sWknqVuHUPpXPQ9mOUQsWmw2GMqPON@NndneIGF3Ihv8tdvtMubbI6r9pt6e92HDNfNi2OSHAxhHiKpyn@kmeO6yGY5elfzlc7wgvhlfBGeCfsWQYPX6vCtqgYxwfePhAbw0kYavQBsAA3AzcDIW4hgIAzg1Pk0kqVSD5RYrPh59ZcscZOcyuB@UOdo9refzKrVJP52hI6Qq6lZDojhOqQJDhe8qsmGC2H2CytAPmdL2xU@C91k7lXfTXQNOCqd8ONewkbAlnDOP4C) is a script that looks for \$(p,m)\$ pairs such that \$(n^p\bmod m)\bmod 4=a_n\$ for all \$n\in[0..9]\$.

It's worth noting that this code takes IEEE-754 precision errors into account. So the results are correct but the math is wrong.

With exact values, we could do instead:

$$\big((n \bmod 10)^{18}\bmod 4011\big)\bmod 4$$

Or better yet, as suggested by [@dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper):

$$\big((n \bmod 10)^{55}\bmod 767\big)\bmod 4$$

For instance, in Python:

#### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 40 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n and(n%10)**55%767%4+f(n/10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc3BCsMgDMbx@57Ci6DdoWq1aQd7GEeRDda0jF729HaXkc/bL4Hkv3@P58ah1nJ/5/WxZMU3VpkXw9o723UpaRpJx2sx3P82df@8@FDFOHv50wuDcBBGYRKOQhJOwhkSmMMe7Ac0fJybWzj2kbDgXDMFnJp@iDTZegI)

---

## JavaScript (ES7), 71 bytes

Expects the amount as a string.

A naive recursive approach that subtracts one coin/bill at a time.

```javascript
n=>(k=10**n.length,g=t=>+n?k>n?g(t,k/=~++i%3?2:2.5):g(t+1,n-=k):t)(i=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdBNDoIwEAXgvadgY9rK30wLIiSFsxBEREgx2rj06kgwUQJpu@yXN33TW/kqn9WjvWtfDed6vMhRyZx2EuFwUEFfq0ZfvUZqmbuq6HJVNFR7XSjfrtvuRcEzHsQsmy5d9JQvO5ZpRlsJbKwG9Rz6OuiHhl4oAeJMhzEnDB3YrRAXiGvkNhQL5GuMbBjbxh5tycSGpwWKNaY2xPmLDIUQiflNbksKsCRF8sdo03aR3LadG5kwSn4Yb/eEabBpTwBOTG0REMzIo@REvpiOHw)

Comment: In Python, I think `(n%10)**55%767%4` is 1 byte shorter.

Comment: @dingledooper Weird. This was within my search bounds but I guess I simply didn't notice it. Thank you!

Comment: "How can you find the black magic (n%10)**55%767%4 that is equivalent to the [0123456789] -> [0112212233] lookup table?" - [asked by jolreal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223381/66833), who doesn't have enough reputation to comment

Comment: I used `n/5%2-n%5/-2` in my Python answer, can that be profitably adapted to JS?

Comment: @xnor Unfortunately, I don't think it's as interesting in JS that it is in Python. By using BigInts to force integer division, the best I can think of so far is [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##fdBNDoIwEAXgvadgA2ljsNM/Cwu8C0EwGjI1Ylx69Uow0Vpsu/3ypm/m0j7aqbudr/cS7bF3bmiwOWBRINOYCyyfBHONlAncDgQZB6SuszjZsd@N9kQGApjNj9KMsQw2v8Y944GJhEnPRGAqYToxc5/ImYRVnsnA6oTx5TD/u3CO0f9EIichnpPmayrs6eVWPZcyEVPmY3q1H8xTI/sBCIz05MAhakKZCt9Wuxc) as well.

Answer (score 14):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>11</s> <s>9</s> 8 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to caird coinheringaahing*

```
ṁo⌈½ṁB5d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f/DnY35j3o6Du0FMpxMU/7//x9toGOoY6RjrGOiY6pjpmOuY6FjqWMIFDTUMTQyMbeIBQA)

```
       d   # get the digits
    ṁB5    # convert them all to base-5
           # (this gives a 1 for each 5-denomination coin needed,
           # as well as the leftover for each digit.
           # We'll need 2 more coins for those with leftover 3 or 4, 
           # and only one more coin if the leftover is 1 or 2.)
ṁo         # So: map across all the base-5 digits
   ½       # dividing each of them by 2
  ⌈        # and then getting the ceiling;
           # and finally output the sum
```

Comment: [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f/DnY35j3o6Du0FMpxMU/7//x9toGOoY6RjrGOiY6pjpmOuY6FjqWMIFDTUMTQyMbeIBQA), using ceiling and halve rather than  increment and integer divide

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing - Nice!  Thankyou very much!

Answer (score 10):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <sup><s>55</s>…<s>41</s></sup> 40 bytes

- -1 byte thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor), for using a string instead of the hard-coded list.

```hs
a=0:tail[i+read[j]|i<-a,j<-"0112212233"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5NDoIwEEb3PQUQdlIzbUHEgCfwBoTFBBCL/AVI3Hh2awmlTRcv38z72hcu77rrlMIMbivKLpenucYqb4uvTCkGbUo9YIxzfYXwCtWjHLJqJI6Ty2AsUtrj5GzK@TPO1ZL696ZeH3Ko9cY0y2H10XVllm3G5ipw9gOEGWKEWxKGOAktRXZ6sVls6WpIkMQSg8Ng7NjjNhNwZMLUhCQB6xpFU7iPI90HYPoA@O4y2F/RxMN4@0XyK58dNoui5TT9AQ)

`a` is the infinite sequence.

### How?

It's not hard to find the recursive formula
$$
a(n)=a\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{10}\right\rfloor\right)+a(n \operatorname{mod} 10)
$$
with the base cases for \$n\in\{0,\ldots,9\}\$ given by
$$
[0,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,3,3].
$$

This means that the infinite list `a` satisfies the equality

```hs
a==[i+j|i<-a,j<-[0,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,3,3]]
```

Now, Haskell is magical, but not magical enough to compute `a` from the definition

```hs
a=[i+j|i<-a,j<-[0,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,3,3]]
```

However, giving the first term explicitly is enough:

```hs
a=0:tail[i+j|i<-a,j<-[0,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,3,3]]
```

The 40-bytes code above is equivalent to this, but shorter.

Comment: Nice recursive list! Looks like compressing the hardcoded list to a string breaks ahead: [TIO](https://tio.run/##PY5NDoIwEEb3PQUQdlIzbUHEgCfwBoTFBBCL/AVI3Hh2awmlTRcv38z72hcu77rrlMIMbivKLpenucYqb4uvTCkGbUo9YIxzfYXwCtWjHLJqJI6Ty2AsUtrj5GzK@TPO1ZL696ZeH3Ko9cY0y2H10XVllm3G5ipw9gOEGWKEWxKGOAktRXZ6sVls6WpIkMQSg8Ng7NjjNhNwZMLUhCQB6xpFU7iPI90HYPoA@O4y2F/RxMN4@0XyK58dNoui5TT9AQ "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>64</s> <s>52</s> <s>50</s> 45 bytes

```r
sum(c(1,2,1:3)[.6*utf8ToInt(scan(,""))-28.4])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7g0VyNZw1DHSMfQylgzWs9Mq7QkzSIk3zOvRKM4OTFPQ0dJSVNT18hCzyRW87@hkYm5xX8A)

Same strategy as [Delfad0r's Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223318/86301), which is nicely explained.

First, `scan(,"")` reads in input as a string. Then, `utf8ToInt(...)-48` takes a string of digits and converts it to a vector of integer digits. This works out shorter than taking input as an integer and splitting it into digits.

The digits from 0 to 9 then have to be mapped to the vector `c(0,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,3,3)`. To do this, consider the vector `a=c(1,2,1,2,3)`. For digit `d`, `a[.4+d*.6]` is the value we want. This uses the fact that when calling a non-integer index in a vector (say `a[2.8]`), R rounds down the index (here `a[2]`), and also the fact that `a[0]` returns `NULL` which will be ignored in the sum.

Putting this operation with the operation to convert the string to digits simplifies to `.6*utf8ToInt(...)-28.4`.

Note that Dominic van Essen has a [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223321/86301) of (currently) the same length with a different strategy.

Comment: <s>Bah!</s> Nice work!

Comment: Your solutions are getting more and more esoteric!

Comment: This is a very, very clever solution!  Well done!  Much better than mine (even if the bytes are the same).  I'm very jealous...  and (despite trying for too long last night) I don't think I'll be able to bet mine any shorter...

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>54</s> <s>51</s> <s>47</s> 45 bytes

*Edit: converted to console input instead of a [full function](https://tio.run/##LY3BCsIwEES/pjQLK@zGlEShuXv3LpJQKOimNM3Br48rCMNjHgzM3uWRyip17kuTdKxFjGCe27GEe7nJYZL6OAKcXIDa3iZHwhwnzMMwRQu9Prft9dEZXZnREp41Hi@ErM7OIxPRD1bB2qzzAfD/C/0L) to try not to fall behind [Robin Ryder's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223316/95126)*

```r
d=utf8ToInt(scan(,''))-48;sum(d>0,d>5,d%%5>2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8W2tCTNIiTfM69Eozg5MU9DR11dU1PXxMK6uDRXI8XOQCfFzlQnRVXV1M5I87@hkYm5xX8A)

Comment: Well done! I'm not giving up yet…

Comment: [It's a tie!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223316/86301)

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
Db5FHĊS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98lydTN40hX8H9Dw6O7FawVjAx0jIHIXMfSQMfQ0FDH0MRcx9DAwABEGAEJQyDLyMTcQsH6cLvKo6Y1Cu7/AQ)

<s>Steals</s> Ports [Dominic Van Essen's Husk answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223323/66833), be sure to upvote that!

### How it works

```
Db5FHĊS - Main link. Takes an integer n on the left
D       - Convert to digits
 b5     - Convert each digit to base 5
   F    - Flatten
    H   - Halve each
     Ċ  - Ceiling of each
      S - SUm
```

---

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
Dị“FȮŀO’D¤S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l4e7uRw1z3E6sO9rg/6hhpsuhJcH/DQ2P7lawVjAy0DEGInMdSwMdQ0NDHUMTcx1DAwMDEGEEJAyBLCMTcwsF68PtKo@a1ii4/wcA)

### How it works

```
Dị“FȮŀO’D¤S - Main link. Takes n on the left
D           - Convert n to digits
         ¤  - Create a nilad:
  “FȮŀO’    -   Compressed integer: 1122122330
        D   -   To digits
 ị          - Index into the digits of this integer
          S - Sum
```

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
S<•δ¬Èº•sèO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/2OZRw6JzWw6tOdxxaBeQWXx4hf///4ZGJuYWAA)

Same approach as my [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223315/66833).

### How it works

```
S<•δ¬Èº•sèO - Program. Input: n
S           - Cast n to digits
 <          - Decrement
  •δ¬Èº•    - Compressed integer: 1122122330
        sè  - Using n's digits, index into the digits of 1122122330
          O - Sum
```

Kudos to [Kevin Cruijssen's excellent integer compressor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/66833)!

Comment: A port of the Husk answer is also shorter in 05AB1E: [`S5δв˜;îO`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/2PTclgubTs@xPrzO//9/QyMTcwsA). And can be another byte shorter in the legacy version of 05AB1E [by removing the leading `S`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f9NyWC5tOz7E@vM7//39DIxNzCwA).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen You're welcome to post that if you'd like, I'm going to keep this as the digit lookup approach

Comment: It's basically the same as your top Jelly answer, but sure, I'll post it as a separated answer.

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 23 bytes

```
L◄Lfo=⁰Σ↑o≤⁰LṖƒ(+İ€m*10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3@fR9BaftHzbR40bzi1@1DYx/1HnEiDb5@HOaccmaWgf2fCoaU2ulqHB////jQwA)

Extremely slow past 11.

### Explanation

```
L◄Lfo=⁰Σ↑o≤⁰LṖƒ(+İ€m*10
              ƒ(        create an infinite list using:
                 İ€     currency denomination builtin: [1,1/2,1/5,...200]
                +       plus
                   m*10 the input mapped to *10
                        this gives [1,1/2,...100] + 10*([1,1/2,...100] + (10*[1,1/2,...100]...))
             Ṗ          powerset(unordered)
        ↑o≤⁰L           take all sequences which have length ≤ input
                        this makes sure everything till [1]*n is in the list
   fo=⁰Σ                filter out the ones which do not sum to the input
 ◄L                     maximum element by length
L                       take the length
```

Comment: "currency denomination builtin"? Seriously? :P

Comment: yep, "Euro coin and bill values" :P

Comment: This would seem to be the perfect challenge for the 'currency denomination builtin', [and yet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223323/95126)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I figured there was a much better method, looking at all the non golflang answers. (I just couldn't pass up using `fix`)

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 39 bytes

```
⌈.4#⌉-⌊#/5⌋&@*IntegerDigits/*Tr
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7/1FPh56J8qOeTt1HPV3K@qaPerrVHLQ880pS01OLXDLTM0uK9bVCiv4HFGXmlUQr69qlOSjHqtUFJyfm1VVzGehwGepwGelwGetwmehwmepwmelwmetwWehwWQKlQNIgeSBtDMJAGUuwGFDQ0MQcpMLAAEwagUiweiMTcwuu2v8A)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 37 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n and n/5%2-n%5/-2+f(n/10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBCsMgFET3cwo3AaWE6I/WJNDDWFKJkP5KsZSe3ioMD@bN5F85Xky1xtsZnvc9CN5YBN4FT26gkQc3jXSJkiejVf0e6XwIs@V34iKiTJw/RSpVNQwIMywcrvBYsMI02azG3OKx9mpgrG@L1h3U0F9k/fIH)

Uses a formula rather than a lookup table for each digit. `n/5%2` counts the five-cent coin, and subtracting `-n%5/-2` is equivalent to adding `(n%5+1)/2` for the one- and two-cent coins.

```python
n%10      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
-----------------------------
n/5%2     0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
0-n%5/-2  0 1 1 2 2 0 1 1 2 2
Total     0 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 3 3
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 39 bytes

```c
f(n){n=n?f(n/10)+""[n%10]:0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5Pa8MwDMX75@ZPYQQpMfOo7KTr0hB62mmHQq7rDiVtt8AiRpqxQ@m@eqbUjoUNPz/pPat6/Kiqvj/HpK5U0JZhaVA9wGQ6nc34zOfwRpHB9w3mt76mTjaHmmIlr0JyDQLpJr8/fj/rr1P8d6kOdI4hOkZH0AvSi0ap75Yn7@K@C/eyJ9Bsl42WwwYMRTHAFnavsIGXstyVoFx4e@p@WpKYi1uP0hUK48kIGyjxZEUaaBW6T0FbB3r2lIgskMHRYcw4Z4OW4KglPiYVGQavtzClrr3iPESfh2id16D7hcmm62GL7B8)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 37 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n&&+"0112212233"[n%10]+f(n/10|0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5Rb4MgFIXf@RWmSStEqxewa@1CH/cH9tiZ1Cg2Lg6d2sWl6293bCA3JHw5h3Mu7/lXPhR93Y1b1ZZyniuhxEltNsEKKGVMH85XZ7WmkAUVVjGFHyBzLz9vdS@xXw0@iXqZly91I1@/VYEhvEtVtGWtrkf/NlYH/0GioWvq8fKmLtFH3uFJnO7I0zOJyVg49oKYPP@LRauGtpFR015xMJ0hC73KAAk9fdNMiEXQkQeZwTMDiFqiiDnilhhKHO2c@@S0vaODJY5SRxSWBKXLO@Y0DovGbU2CUnBZG9GUGHun@wBsHwAzWQpmiyaW7P9@kf4C)

Comment: Golfed your JS one: `f=n=>n&&+"311221223"[n%9]+f(n/10|0)`

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms How does that work?

Comment: Oh wait, it doesn't. Sorry about that (forgot `n%10` can be `0` with `n` being nonzero)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 48 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:x and int("0112212233"[x%10])+f(x/10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRocKqQiExL0UhM69EQ8nA0NDICIiMjZWiK1QNDWI1tdM0KvQNDTT/FxQBVSikaRgamZhbaP4HAA)

49 bytes in Python 3 because you'd need `//` for floor division.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
ＩΣ⭆Ｓ⭆↨Ｉι⁵Ｌ↨λ³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI7g0VyO4BMhP900s0PDMKygtgXA1NHUUEBJOicWpEA2ZQHFTIPZJzUsvyYBI5OgoGGtCgPX//4ZGJuYW/3XLcgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   Ｓ            Convert input to a string
  ⭆             Map over characters and join
       ι        Current character
      Ｉ         Cast to integer
     ↨  ⁵       Convert to base 5
    ⭆           Map over base 5 digits and join
           λ    Current digit
          ↨ ³   Convert to base 3
         Ｌ      Take the length
 Σ              Take the (digital) sum
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Table of base 5 digit to base 3 length:

```
Decimal Base 3 Length
0       []     0
1       [1]    1
2       [2]    1
3       [1, 0] 2
4       [1, 1] 2
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), `d`, 5 bytes

```
5vτ½⌈
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=d&code=5v%CF%84%C2%BD%E2%8C%88&inputs=37&header=&footer=)

A port of the Jelly answer which is a port of short husk answer.

### Explained

```
5vτ½⌈
5vτ   # convert each digit of the input to base 5
   ½  # halve each item in that list (halving vectorises all the way down)
    ⌈ # ceiling each item in that list
      # -d deep sums the list and implicitly outputs
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>20</s> 15 bytes

```
.
$*1,
1{5}|11?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYo7CoBAEEP7nENBRGSyH3e3svQaWljYWIidevZxFsKDvOTa7@PctO2WVUc0PQfwid9LzqoCwsEjIGJCQkYBTZoVeEtCqZVgSLaIVDhDfbmQ8g8) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.
$*1,
```

Convert each digit to unary separately.

```
1{5}|11?
```

Count the number of 5s, 2s and 1s needed to make each digit.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
5δв˜;îO
```

Port of [*@Dominic van Essen*'s Husk answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223323/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

Uses the legacy version of 05AB1E to get rid of a leading `S` that would be required in the new version of 05AB1E in this case, due to the way the `δ` acts on strings/integers.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f9NyWC5tOz7E@vM7//39DIxNzCwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/03NbLmw6Pcf68Dr//zr/ow10DHWMdIx1THRMdcx0zHUsdCx1DIGCQFEDHWMgMtexBHENdQxNzIEyBgYgwghIgFQZmZhbxAIA).

**Explanation:**

```python
 δ       # Map each digit in the (implicit) input-integer to:
5 в      #  A base-5 list
   ˜     # Flatten this list of lists
    ;    # Halve each integer
     î   # Ceil each float
      O  # Sum the integers in the list together
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```